# Call Parameter as Reference to Array of Unknown Bound in C++

Tags: c++, function, c++11, parameters, c++17

I am trying to understand whether references to array of unknown bound can be used as call parameter in functions in C++. Below is the example that i have:

**EXAMPLE 1**

```
void func(int (&a)[])
{
}
int main()
{
   cout << "Hello World" << endl; 
   int k[] = {1,2,3};
  // k[0] = 3;
   func(k);
   return 0;
}
```

To my surprise this example 1 above works when compiled with GCC 10.1.0 and C++11 but doesn't work with GCC version lower that 10.x. I don't think that we can have references to arrays of unknown size in C++. But then how does this code compile at the following link: [successfully compiled](https://wandbox.org/permlink/f5OoPvho9L77832B)

My second question is that **can we do this for a function template**? For example,

**EXAMPLE 2**

```
template<typename T1>
void foo(int (&x0)[])
{
}
```

Is example 2 valid C++ code in any version like C++17 etc. I saw usage of example 2 in a book where they have `int (&x0)[]` as a function parameter of a template function.

Comment: Not sure what your template adds... Did you mean `template<typename T>void foo(T(&a)[])` or `template<size_t N> void foo(int (&a)[N])`?

Comment: Using `typeid(a)` I can see that `a` is just that, an array of unknown bound. Not a pointer, nor a fancy auto-makes-template thing. Interesting... but hardly useful.

Comment: @Jarod42 It doesn't add anything. Instead the user will explicitly provide the template argument. The point being that is the usage of reference to array of unknown bound legal in C++ whether in nontemplate or template functions. It is just an example. You can remove the type parameter if you like.

Comment: gcc is rather lax with default settings. Try `-pedantic-errors`: https://wandbox.org/permlink/RVCutmkxYc18Mvyd

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number But the program you sent the link to works with C++2a.

Comment: I see no reasons template version should behave differently than the non-template version. (Notice than detecting error with template is generally harder for compiler).

Comment: It was perhaps that paper implemented: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0388r4.html so it obviously can't be in C++11

Comment: BTW, I think the line `int k[] = {1,2,3};` declares k of *known* size (3). It is the same as `int k[3] = {1, 2, 3};`. In any case, good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't think that we can have references to arrays of unknown size in C++.

That used to be the case, although it was considered to be a language defect. It has been allowed since C++17.

Note that implicit conversion from array of known bound to array of unknown bound - which is what you do in `main` of example 1 - wasn't allowed until C++20.

> Is example 2 valid C++ code in any version like C++17

Yes; the template has no effect on whether you can have a reference to array of unknown bound.

Comment: When you said that "implicit conversion from array of know bound to array of unknow bound", are you talking about the statement `int k[] = {1,2,3};` or the statement ` func(k);`? I think that you mean the latter but i want to confirm.

Comment: @AanchalSharma I mean the latter. In the former, the type is *adjusted* to array of *known* bound.